# ECS task healthCheck: curl request to SOAP operation never succeeds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, health-check, ecs-taskdefinition

Hello: I'd like to invoke a SOAP operation for the ECS task healthCheck.

Does anybody know how it can be achieved?

a) cURL with SOAP request makes the task Unhealthy (from task definition)

```
    "healthCheck": {
        "command": [
            "CMD-SHELL",
            "curl -s --fail --request POST --header \"Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\" --data \"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ser='http://service.cou.edu'><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ser:healthCheckTask/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>\" http://localhost:8080/myctx/MyService || exit 1"
        ],
        "interval": 30,
        "timeout": 5,
        "retries": 3,
        "startPeriod": 2
    },
```

Note: When this cURL command is placed in the Dockerfile HEALTHCHECK, it always succeeds. So, I'm sure the command is correct.
I expected the task to become Healthy when configuring this healthCheck in the task definition.

b) cURL just loading the WSDL of the SOAP service makes task Healthy (from task definition)

```
    "healthCheck": {
        "command": [
            "CMD-SHELL",
            "curl -s --fail http://localhost:8080/myctx/MyService?WSDL || exit 1"
        ],
        "interval": 30,
        "timeout": 5,
        "retries": 3,
        "startPeriod": 2
    },
```

Note: It also works fine when placed in the HEALTHCHECK of the Dockerfile